# Add a magento layout

Tags: magento, layout, magento-1.7

How to add a layout on magento system? I want to add a new layout which can be selected from administration panel as well.

I am trying to make two layout on the website. One layout with banner and another without banner. Lets say I want

`2Columns-right.phtml` and `2Column-right-wBanner.phtml`

How to add this?

Answer (score 2):

For This you Need to create a custom module.

In Module etc/config.xml copy following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
    <page>
        <layouts>
            <custom_layout_wbanner>
                <label>Custom Layout Banner</label>
                <template>page/2Column-right-wBanner.phtml</template>
            </custom_layout_wbanner>
        </layouts>
    </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

Hope This Help !!

Comment: A module isn't required. This can be put in local.xml. Having a module to put in a layout doesn't make much sense IMO.

Comment: @ZacharySchuessler, I placed this in local.xml, but I cannot get the option in the administrative. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: In local.xml global tag please place following code: 
<page>
 <layouts>
  <custom_layout_wbanner>
   <label>Custom Layout Banner</label>
   <template>page/2Column-right-wBanner.phtml</template>
  </custom_layout_wbanner>
 </layouts>
</page>